# How to get single object from array?

Tags: python, rest, api, web-applications, get

I want to GET a single object from an array in my api. How do I do it.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Auth-App-Key': 'BvBdsGHQKc1dOOWGMcy0f07XXXXXXXXX0zv5zxHNDhf4P5NFElwKsZWWV3QceKq5J'
}
request = Request('https://XXXXXXt.com/api/v1.0/clients/123', headers=headers)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

Response:

```
{"id":123,
"isLead":false,
"clientType":1,
"contacts: [ {
"id":174,
"clientId":123,
"email":"mmayert@example.net",
"phone":"1-210-900-9283",
"name":null,
"isBilling":true,
"isContact":true,
"types":[
{"id":1,
"name":"Billing"},
{"id":2,"name":"General"}]}]**,
```

I have an existing API and I'm trying to create a web app with Twilio for customer support. When a ccertain phone number calls ie. a client, it triggers a web hook (the web app) that goes and formulates a GET command to retrieve the client with that certain phone number so it can greet him

Comment: Are you asking how to write an API using python as a backend or are you asking how to interface to an existing API using python? Your question is missing a lot of key details.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: I have an existing API and I'm trying to create a web app with Twilio for customer support. When a ccertain phone number calls ie. a client, it triggers a web hook (the web app) that goes and formulates a GET command to retrieve the client with that certain phone number so it can greet him.